# Prove $\sum_{v=0}^n{\alpha \choose v}{\beta \choose n-v} = {\alpha + \beta \choose n}$ using induction on $n$

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

For $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{C}$ and $v \in \mathbb{N}$ let
$${\alpha \choose 0} = 1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ {\alpha \choose v} = \prod_{j=1}^v\frac{\alpha - j + 1}{j}.$$
The claim is that
$$\sum_{v=0}^n{\alpha \choose v}{\beta \choose n-v} = {\alpha + \beta \choose n}.$$
I try to prove this by using induction $n$.
The base cases are $n = 0$ and $n = 1$:
$$n = 0:  {\alpha \choose 0}{\beta \choose 0} = 1 = {\alpha + \beta \choose 0}$$
$$n = 1:  {\alpha \choose 0}{\beta \choose 1} + {\alpha \choose 1}{\beta \choose 0} = {\beta\choose 1} + {\alpha \choose 1} = \beta + \alpha = {\alpha + \beta \choose 1}$$
Induction hypothesis: assume for $n = k-1$
$$\sum_{v=0}^{k-1}{\alpha \choose v}{\beta \choose k-v} = {\alpha + \beta \choose k-1}.$$
Then for $n = k$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{v=0}^{k}{\alpha \choose v}{\beta \choose k-v} &= \sum_{v=0}^{k-1}{\alpha \choose v}{\beta \choose k-v} + {\alpha \choose k}{\beta \choose 0}\\
&= \sum_{v=0}^{k-1}{\alpha \choose v}{\beta \choose k-v} + {\alpha \choose k}\\
&= {\alpha + \beta \choose k-1} + {\alpha \choose k}\\
&= \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha + \beta - j + 1}{j} + \prod_{j=1}^k\frac{\alpha - j + 1}{j}\\
&= \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha + \beta - j + 1}{j} + \prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha - j}{k-j}
\end{align}
Now I'm stuck. I'd appreciate it if someone can help me.

Comment: It is the well-known Vandermonde identity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the link. However, they don't use induction. I was wondering if we can still prove it using induction.

Comment: @yisishoujo But $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are complex  numbers. So I can't do that right?

Comment: then you multiply $n$ on both side and split $n$ as $n-v+v$

Comment: @yisishoujo I'm not sure I understand. So we have then
$$(n-v+v)\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha + \beta - j + 1}{j} + (n-v+v)\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha - j}{k-j}$$
on the RHS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean LHS is equal to
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\frac{1}{n}  \sum v\binom{\alpha}{v} \cdot \binom{\beta}{n-v} + \binom{\alpha}{v} \cdot (n-v)\binom{\beta}{n-v} \\
= & \frac{1}{n}  \sum \alpha \binom{\alpha-1}{v-1} \cdot \binom{\beta}{n-v} + \binom{\alpha}{v} \cdot \beta \binom{\beta-1}{n-1-v} \\
= & \frac{1}{n} (\alpha + \beta) \binom{\alpha+\beta-1}{n-1} \\
= & \binom{\alpha + \beta}{n}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: So you dont need the induction hypothesis here?

Comment: it is used in the third line to get $\binom{\alpha+\beta-1}{n-1}$